# Android style a button as circle (multiple concentric)

Tags: android, button, styles, geometry

I am trying to create a strip of buttons inside a linear layout by providing custom styles for the button. I want the buttons to look like the following (The button 4 indicates a pressed button, which I know can be done using states and isn't an issue).

[image: LINK]

I have been trying to get the initial look of the button using the multiple Ring shapes (See code below) but didn't succeed since in the editor it looked fine but when I ran the code the gradient behind the buttons (applied on the linearlayout) showed through the innermost ring.

```
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="ring" android:thickness="8dp" android:useLevel="false">
                    <solid android:color="@color/ColorDarkBlue" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="ring" android:thickness="7dp" android:useLevel="false">
                    <solid android:color="@color/ColorGrey" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="ring" android:thickness="2dp" android:useLevel="false">
                    <solid android:color="@color/ColorWhite" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
```

Since the approach above didn't work because of the innermost ring being transparent, I switched the innermost ring to an oval shape but it scaled to the entire button's surface covering everything. Can someone kindly tell me how to resolve this.